# Google Sheets Vlookup Matching

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have two Gsheets. The first sheet looks like this…

```
Fruit_Name
Apple
Banana
Orange
Grape
Watermelon 
Mango
Strawberry
Melon
Blueberry
Tangerine
Papaya
```

The second sheet looks like this…

```
Red_Fruits  Yellow_Fruits    Purple_Fruits    Orange_Fruits   Grade
Apple       Banana           Blueberry        Orange          A
Apple       Banana           Blackberry       Papaya          B
Cranberry   Lemon            Grape            Tangerine       C
Watermelon  Banana           Blackberry       Melon           B
Strawberry  Mango            Plum             Papaya          D
```

This is the desired result…

```
Fruit_Name  Grade
    Apple   A, B
    Banana  A, B, C
    Orange  A
    Grape   C
    …
    Watermelon 
    Mango
    Strawberry
    Melon
    Blueberry
    Tangerine
    Blackberry
    Papaya
```

The desired result is basically having the solution return multiple  grades as needed based on the second column. How can I get this is google sheets? Note column A is a short list of fruits than column B which I why I need it.
Thanks.

Comment: So in the question title you mention vlookup. How did it work or not work? Show what you attempted.

Comment: I tried a bunch of VLOOKUP methods, but nothing worked as I wanted it to. I am pretty new to google sheets, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following formula a try:

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(Sheet2!$E$2:$E,MMULT(--(Sheet2!$A$2:$D=A2),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Sheet2!$A$2:$D$2)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(ROWS(D2:G), COLUMNS(D2:G))&"×"&D2:G&"♥×"&H2:H&","), "×"), 
 "select max(Col3) where Col3<>',' group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "♥")), ",$", ), 2, 0)))
```

[image]